# Banking site POST data obsfucated. How to achieve this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am logged in to my banking site and I see this kind of form POST data in the Developer tools of Chrome:

```
accountNo: removed for security reason
branchCode: removed for security reason
fromDate: U2FsdGVkX1+73zpLsKOLUO+go3Ft2z9qV+rvOGEfcnk=
toDate: U2FsdGVkX1/Ur2O/lk5d5J5uiHVFjeIfC/hBBucUodg=
order: 1
noOfRows: ALL
pageNumber: 1
fileFormat: 
request_Id: 
radiobuttonPeriod: 6Month
accountType: A1
gkkj: iit9133r7apgb1ieh69bfs82a5d9166d
```

I wanted to understand how is the data obsfucated? Example the accountNo and branchCode were in plain text in the developer tools but the fromDate and toDate is obsfuscated. Additionally there is a cryptic key like gkkj which is think is some token code so if I refresh the page it would sign me out. But this token name and code keeps on changing example on one of the other pages I see this as token:

```
t34j: hpo9mcs4rp2jrmohber34ifm8q22rn8a
```

Is there any popular library in C# which can achieve this or a general understanding of why would somebody obfuscate the POST data would be helpful. Already the site has SSL certificate then:

1. Why would one want to do this?
2. How to achieve this?

Please let me know.

I am trying to understand

1. Why would one want to do this?
2. How to achieve this?

Comment: The `fromDate` and `toDate` are just base64 encoded, and seem to be `Salted:<key>`. For the rotating `gkkj`, etc, I think you'd get a better answer over at [security.se], and then take their answers and try to reproduce the effect.